# how to write this code in swagger.io for schema

Tags: json, yaml

code

{
        "total": "string",
        "money": "string",
        "firsttype": "string",
        "secondType": "string",
        "requestDate": "string",
        "FirstParty": [
            {
                "key": "string",
                "value": "string"
            }
        ],
        "secondParty": [
            {
                "key": "string",
                "value": "string"
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: what have you tired?  A simple google search gives you online tools that convert from json to yaml, have you tired those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaml is also a key value pair, just the format is different. Nested JSON is identified by the indentation.

Comment: when i put this code into my file then occur following errors : 
1. Not a valid parameter defination.

Comment: Please use any of the online JSON to YAML converter for your requirement.

Comment: actually i want to write this code as schema in swagger.io ... so this is a general answer but not for making schema.